# Copy build to server - shipitjs deployment

Tags: deployment, shipitjs

I am running a react application on my local machine. I need to create the build and copy the build folder to server. 
I am using shipit for deployment. The files are as follows.

Shipitfile.js

```
var utils = require('shipit-utils');
module.exports = function (shipit) {
  require('shipit-deploy')(shipit);

  shipit.initConfig({
    default: {
      workspace: '.',
      dirToCopy: 'dist/',
      keepReleases: 2,
      deleteOnRollback: false,
      key: '~/.ssh/id_rsa',
      shallowClone: true
    },
    staging: {
      servers: 'user@xx.x.x.xxx/',
      deployTo: '/home/username/Desktop/appFolder/'
    }
  });

  utils.registerTask(shipit, 'deploy', [
    'deploy:init',
    'deploy:update',
    'deploy:publish',
    'deploy:clean',
    'deploy:finish'
  ]);
};
```

deploy.js

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("npm run-script install", function () {
  exec("npm run-script build", function () {
    environment = process.env.env || "staging";
    var deployProcess = exec("shipit " + environment + " deploy");
    deployProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });
  });
});
```

When i run the command **env=staging yarn deploy**, it generates the build folder(dist/) but it is not copying to the specified path. i need to deploy the dist folder to the specified path on server.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Update 1

```
I have modified the code as follows 

var exec = require('child_process').exec;
environment = process.env.env || "staging";
var deployProcess = exec("shipit " + environment + " deploy");
deployProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

Now when i run yarn deploy i am getting the following error

> 'deploy:update' errored after 9.49 s
>
> TypeError: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
>       at Object.module.exports [as resolve] (/home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/path2/posix/resolve.js:14:10)
>       at /home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:103:47
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:39:191)
>       at /home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:39:437
>       at new Promise ()
>       at /home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:39:99
>       at remoteCopy (/home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:112:22)
>       at Shipit. (/home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:211:11)
>       at Generator.next ()
>       at step (/home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:39:191)
>       at /home/prajeesh/Desktop/projects/projects/floor22_hr3_reactJS/node_modules/shipit-deploy/lib/tasks/deploy/update.js:39:361
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say don't call you task "deploy", it will conflict with the one inside shipit-deploy. Let's call it `upload_my_build` for example.

This is what I do for this specific problem.

1. run you build commmand and produce your build_folder
2. create the task and use copyToRemote (it's rsync under the hood, so make sure you have it)
3. trigger the task when the `updated` event of the deploy gets triggered.

_

```
utils.registerTask(shipit, 'upload_my_build', () =>{
    return shipit.copyToRemote('build_folder', shipit.releasePath)
});

shipit.on('init', () => {
  shipit.on('updated', () => {
    shipit.start('upload_my_build')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ssh-deploy-release](https://github.com/la-haute-societe/ssh-deploy-release)

```
const Deployer = require('ssh-deploy-release');

const options = {
    localPath: 'upload_my_build', // put here your build dolder
    host: 'my.server.com',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    deployPath: '/var/www/vhost/path/to/project'
};

const deployer = new Deployer(options);
deployer.rollbackToPreviousRelease(() => {
    console.log('Ok !')
});
```